# Q_ASSERT has different behavior when my project is built in Visual Studio vs. Qt Creator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator, assert

This seems to be a bug, because on Qt Creator, Q_ASSERT(false) causes my application to quit even though the documentation says it should allow you to break at the assertion:

> On Windows, for debug builds, this function will report a _CRT_ERROR
>   enabling you to connect a debugger to the application.

### On Qt Creator:

When compiling my project in Qt Creator+MinGW, the code `Q_ASSERT(false);` causes the program to display this message (screenshot below), after which the application quits:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

[image]

and Application Output pane shows this debug output:

```
ASSERT: "false" in file ..\IntegrateWithQt\main.cpp, line 6
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
```

### On Visual Studio:

When compiling the same project using Visual Studio (I import it with the Qt Addin), I get a much more useful Abort/Retry/Ignore dialog, where clicking Retry breaks the program at the location of the assert:

[image]

The version of Qt I link to both in Qt Creator and in Visual Studio is 4.8.1. Both projects are built in Debug mode.

So how do I get Qt Creator to allow me to break at the line of the assertion in debug mode?

Comment: How do I fix it on Qt Creator. This must be a bug.

Comment: Notice that one is "runtime" and the other is "debug".  Maybe a build setting?

Comment: Both the Qt Creator and the Visual Studio project are built in debug mode.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt Creator, but when you get the dialog you mention, maybe you still can attach a debugger to the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you are using Mingw in Qt Creator and MSVC (obviously) in Visual studio. Different compilers produce different code.

Try using MSVC in Creator (you will need to get a Qt version that was built with that compiler to do that!) and see whether there still are differences.

Answer (score 2):

1. Probably in QtCreator's .pro file is not set NDEBUG (check it in QtCreator's compile output)
2. Use standard c++ assert http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Comment: NDEBUG is not set at the debug build. But isn't it about **disabling** debugging?

Comment: Do you use VS + MinGW? I mean is Qt built by the same compiler?

Comment: I haven't built Qt myself, I've downloaded the desktop version for both Visual Studio and for MinGW using Qt SDK. I would guess that Qt Creator uses the one built with MinGW, and VS uses the one built with VS.

Comment: You're right, when I added a built from Qt Creator, but using Qt for MSVC2010, the resulting application showed the Abort/Retry/Ignore assert dialog.